# Set HTML with style in a GrapesJs component

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I use GrapesJs and I want to update the html content of a component.
So I use the `components` method of a component : `cmp.components('<h1 style="text-align:left">Hello</h1>')`.
But when I retrieve the html content of my component (`cmp.toHTML()`) the style is not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with my grapesjs **version**. I was in `0.21.1` and the problem disappears using `0.21.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace cmp.components(...) with below code

```js
cmp.addComponent({
  tagName: 'h1',
  content: 'Hello', // Text inside component
  style: { text-align: 'right'},
});
```